# new to iOS - not able to download and run project

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I downloaded the Flashlight project from this [trusted site](http://oreilly.com/missingmanuals/cds/iphoneappdevelopmentmm/) , in xcode i clicked on "open other" and choose this project. But when I run it it gives me the error:

the run destination my mac 64-bit is not valid for running the scheme 'Flashlight'

the scheme 'Flashlight' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination my MAC 64-bit. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode.

I tried this: Autocreating schemes (Scheme > Manage schemes > Autocreate schemes) 
I then closed and re-opened xCode. still got same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the issue is not in the schemes, it is in the build settings of the project and its SDK missing.

1.click the project on the left side of the Xcode when your project is open. 
2.then on the right side navigate to the build settings.
3.under the base SDK pane, click on the right side and open up the drop down menu.
4.then select the type of the SDK you want.

from there you can select to run the project on the mac or iOS.

now this project is missing some basic framework when its run on mac 10.8. so i suggest you run it in iOS.